# Adding multiple images with preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple images that need to be uploaded and in preview user should be able to select one of those images for their main image.My idea was to assign them an id with counted but that doesn't seem to work,they always have the same id of number of images that are uploaded. This is js a code that I am using

```
$(function() {

  var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

    if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $($.parseHTML("<img height=' 50px' width='50px' class='img-id' id='" +i+"'>")).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);

        }
    }

};

$('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is because you declared `i` as a global variable, so when the `onload` method is called it is getting the `i` global value which is now equal to your array size.

Fix by declaring the var properly.

```js
$(function() {

    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                let index = i;
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML("<img height=' 50px' width='50px' class='img-id' id='" + index + "'>"))
                      .attr('src', event.target.result)
                      .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);

                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);

            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```