# Upload multiple files with preview and input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I try to create a Uploadform with 2 Functions:

1. preview images before upload | Done by this Thread: [Adding multiple images with preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912127/adding-multiple-images-with-preview)
2. Show multiple input fields for each upload file. and send them in req.files

i have no clue how to archive this :(

```
<form name="uploadForm" ref='uploadForm' id='uploadForm' action='' method='post' encType="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="preview-images"></div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="uploadSubmit" class="uploadSubmit"><%=res.__('Upload')%>button>
</form>


   $(document).ready(function () {
                        let imagesPreview = function (input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
                            if (input.files) {
                                let filesAmount = input.files.length;
                                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                                    let reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = function (event) { 
                                        $($.parseHTML("<img>")).attr("src", event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        $("#_uploadFiles").on("change", function () {
                            $("div.preview-images").html("");
                            imagesPreview(this, "div.preview-images");
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML (just the necessary parts) to go with the JavaScript? Please reduce the questions to a single question. This is because SO is a library of questions and answer; the probability of helping someone in the future will be much higher when the question is specific.

Comment: You're HTML doesn't have an `<input type="file"/>`, but your JS is expecting there to be one with the id `_uploadFiles`. What does *Show multiple input fields for each upload file* mean? You can add multiple files with a single input.